# Console showing error while launching applet

Tags: java

I am getting the below error in console while launching applet in java.

```
Missing Application-Name manifest attribute for: http://localhost:7001/config_files/ORBIClient.jar
0
handleLaunchJVM(): RemoteJVMLauncer.setCallBack for 1
handleLaunchJVM(): now unregisterApplet 1
```

Could anybody please tell me the solution for this?

Comment: applets are dead

Comment: Now what should i do?? please tell me??

Comment: rewrite using a modern paradigm

Comment: But we use applets. Please tell me if u have the solution for this.